# How to put a loop in a loop

Tags: random, procedural-programming, webmathematica

I am doing some work with black-scholes. As commented within my code, I need my while loop to run 100 times. I am not sure if the best way to do this is with a nested argument or placing a for loop or another while within the while already.

```
dt = .0001;
mu = 0;
gamma = .005;
t = .0833;
i = t/dt;
random = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, dt^.5], 10^2];
Z = Table[0, 10^2 + 1];
Z[[1]] = .0158;
i = 2;
While[i <= 834,
Z[[i]] = Z[[i - 1]] + mu*dt + (gamma)*random[[i - 1]];
i++
];
(*have to make this loop 100 times*) 
ListPlot[Z, DataRange -> {0, 100*dt}, PlotRange -> All];
Print[Z];
```

Answer (score 6):

Define `random` using `SetDelayed` so that each time it is used it gives a different random vector:

```
lngth = 834;
rndm := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, dt^.5], lngth - 1]
```

Instead of using a loop you can use

```
Prepend[Accumulate[rndm] gamma + mu dt + .0158, .0158]
```

to get a random vector of length 834.

You can use the above with `Table` to generate as many random vectors as you like:

```
k = 20;
SeedRandom[1]
W = Table[Prepend[Accumulate[rndm] gamma + mu dt + .0158, .0158], k];
```

Visualize:

```
ListLinePlot[W, 
 DataRange -> {0, lngth  dt}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[20]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
k = 200;
W = Table[Prepend[Accumulate[rndm] gamma + mu dt + .0158, .0158], k];
ListLinePlot[W, DataRange -> {0,  lngth dt}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25]]
```

[image]

Comment: The graph is really beautiful but the the outputted W is not correct. It is supposed to give a list of 100X834. I am assuming K is influencing the list length, but even when I change K I do not get the correct dimensions. How do I fix this?

Comment: @sabrina, updated with a correction; now `W` is a 100X834 random matrix.